# Method definition without a name in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently looked at sample code for a controller in a rails project which included a method definition in a class without defining the name of the method like so:

```
def begin
  redirect_to :action => :buy, :PaymentAction => params[:paymentaction]
rescue Errno::ENOENT => exception
  flash[:error] = exception
  redirect_to :controller => 'wppro', :action => 'exception'  
end
```

Is this a way of defining a constructor in rails?

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: PayPal express checkout sample implementation provided by PayPal has this bit of code in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, `begin` is just the name of a method; it's unrelated to the `begin`…`rescue` syntax for handling exceptions (in which the `begin` is sometimes optional). `foo.begin` is valid syntax for calling this method as well.

Since we're inside a Rails controller, `begin` is additionally the name of an action.

Constructors are defined with the `initialize` instance method.